# Create transaction using delete method... failed

Tags: php, idiorm

I want to create transaction query with this code :

```
    // Start a transaction
    ORM::get_db()->beginTransaction();

    //this work
    $prs = Model::factory('PenyediaJasaORM')->find_one(77);
    $prs->delete();

    //yes this not work, i know 
    $klas = Model::factory('PenyediaJasaKlasifikasiORM')->find_one(100);
    $klas->delete();


    // Commit a transaction
    ORM::get_db()->commit();
```

yes on $prs query it works. i made the $klas not work to see the outcome. 
but why i got error 'Fatal error: Call to a member function delete() on boolean in'.

i think the appropriate error would be FALSE not FATAL ERROR since those query is transaction.

please give suggestion to me if i am not fully understood transaction using multiple delete query.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
Model::factory('PenyediaJasaKlasifikasiORM')->find_one(100);
```

returns false if doesn't find anything. You should check if your $klas variable is not false, call $klas->delete()

```
if($klas) {
    $klas->delete();
}
```

Comment: thanks u but not expected answer... this question specifically is about idiorm ... i dont understand why should use if... 

if we talk about cleanness  code why idiorm not using if in delete method it self ??

Comment: Because if your query returns false, it isn't an idiorm object. You could argue that idiorm should return an empty idiorm object when it doesn't find anything, and when you call delete it tells you it is empty, but that's how that framework works. You should open an issue in idiorm's github page suggesting it